# Problems with randomly moving in unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a creature that is moving randomly and when hits a wall it changes a direction, but after some time it disappears (which it shouldn't). Can anyone tell me why and how can I fix that? Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

public class Random_moving : MonoBehaviour{

    public Vector3 target;

    public float speed=10f;

    Vector3 screenPos;

    int direction = 1;

    void  Start (){
        target = Random.insideUnitSphere * 5;
        transform.Rotate(target);
    }
    void  Update (){
        transform.position += (transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime)*direction;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D coll){
                Debug.Log ("hit.");
                if (coll.gameObject.tag == "maze"){                 
                        if (screenPos.x < Screen.width / 2){
                                direction = -1;
                                Debug.Log ("change_2.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please copy and paste your code into this question. Make it to be complete without visiting other site (which can be possible broken)

Answer (score 2):

If the creature has to change its direction, you should do:

```
direction *= -1;
```

and not

```
direction = -1;
```

Actually, the direction is changed only at the first collision with a wall. Probably, this causes the creature to "enter" the wall at the second collision, since the direction stills the same.

Comment: And how can I make the creature to change its direction everytime there is a collision?

Comment: Actually, you are "filtering" your collisions using the collider's tag (if (coll.gameObject.tag == "maze")). Just remove that if statement to "catch" all collisions.

Comment: Oh, I meant, how to stop disappearing the creature? Even with direction *= -1; it still disappears, but it shows after some time.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's impossible to tell without seeing the project. I can only suggest to reduce your scene's complexity (maybe removing some colliders/walls) and see if the problem persists. So, you can understand if that's a problem due to collisions or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have two independent problems. First, as [Andrea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24650397/3517635) already told you, you're not toggling your direction with each collision. If `1` is forwards and `-1` backwards, you're always going backwards after the first collision. To toggle the direction simply multiply with `-1`.

```
direction *= -1;
```

Second, you're using `transform.position` to move your creature. By setting `transform.position` directly, you're basically ignoring collisions. It's like teleporting the object to its destination, even if it's into another object. To trigger collisions you need to move your creature with the help of the physics engine. Either by applying a force to the creature or by using the function [`Rigidbody2D.MovePosition()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html).

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    rigidbody2D.MovePosition(rigidbody2D.position + (transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime * direction));
}
```

An important hint from the [manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html):

> It is important to understand that the actual position change will only occur during the next physics update therefore calling this method repeatedly without waiting for the next physics update will result in the last call being used. For this reason, it is recommended that it is called during the FixedUpdate callback.

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot.
But know I have another problem. After it hits the "wall", I want the creature to change its direction, not just to move like a ping pong ball, if you know what I mean. I've tried some stuffs, but they didn't work. Any suggestions how can I do this?